# Could not find the correct Provider<CounterProvider> above this MyWidget Widget

Tags: flutter, type-providers

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MyWidget Widget
This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
  Make sure that MyWidget is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:
  ```consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
home: MultiProvider(
providers: [
ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CounterProvider()),
ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SettingsProvider()),
],
child: CounterWidget(),
),
);
}
}

abstract class BaseProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
double executionSpeed = 1.0;

void updateExecutionSpeed(double speed) {
executionSpeed = speed;
notifyListeners();
}
}

abstract class BaseProvider2 extends BaseProvider {
double executionSpeed2 = 1.0;

void updateExecutionSpeed2(double speed) {
executionSpeed = speed;
notifyListeners();
}
}

class CounterProvider extends BaseProvider2 {
int _value = 0;

int get value => _value;

void increment() {
_value++;
notifyListeners();
}

void decrement() {
_value--;
notifyListeners();
}
}

class SettingsProvider extends BaseProvider2 {
bool _darkMode = false;

bool get darkMode => _darkMode;

void toggleDarkMode() {
_darkMode = !_darkMode;
notifyListeners();
}
}

class CounterWidget extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final counterProvider = Provider.of(context);
final settingsProvider = Provider.of(context);

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Counter App'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Count: ${counterProvider.executionSpeed}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                counterProvider.increment();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyWidget()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Switch(
          value: settingsProvider.darkMode,
          onChanged: (value) {
            settingsProvider.toggleDarkMode();
          },
        ),
        Text('Dark Mode: ${settingsProvider.darkMode ? 'On' : 'Off'}'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final counterProvider = Provider.of(context);
final settingsProvider = Provider.of(context);
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('My Widget'),
),
body: Center(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
Text(
'Count: ${counterProvider.executionSpeed}',
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
),
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.add),
onPressed: () {
counterProvider.increment();
},
),
IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
onPressed: () {
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyWidget()),
);
},
),
],
),
Switch(
value: settingsProvider.darkMode,
onChanged: (value) {
settingsProvider.toggleDarkMode();
},
),
Text('Dark Mode: ${settingsProvider.darkMode ? 'On' : 'Off'}'),
],
),
),
);
}
}

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).